# Python PIL - why can't I use ImageOps.colorize here.?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I was trying to make a 3D image with PIL and python. But I got AssertionError that said '`assert image.mode == "L"`', on the line which includes '`(red_img = ImageOps.colorize(right_img_developed,(0, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0)))` and `cyan_img = ImageOps.colorize(left_img_developed,(0, 0, 0), (0, 255, 255))`', I tried googling the error but I couldn't get any answers. I also looked at the documentation but couldn't find any useful help. Thanks in advance.:  That is my code:

```
import io, re, requests
from PIL import  Image, ImageOps, ImageEnhance

imgpth ='path/image.jpg'

right_img = Image.open(imgpth)
right_img_resized = right_img.resize((400, 400))
right_img_developed = right_img_resized.transform((400, 300), Image.QUAD, data =(0, 0, 100, 400, 300, 400, 400, 0), resample=Image.BILINEAR)

left_img_url = re.sub('FRB', 'FLB', imgpth)
left_img = Image.open(left_img_url)
left_img_resized = left_img.resize((400, 400))
left_img_developed = left_img_resized.transform((400, 300), Image.QUAD, data =(0, 0, 100, 400, 300, 400, 400, 0), resample=Image.BILINEAR)

red_img = ImageOps.colorize(right_img_developed,(0, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0))
cyan_img = ImageOps.colorize(left_img_developed,(0, 0, 0), (0, 255, 255))

blend = Image.blend(red_img, cyan_img, 0.5)

red_img.show()
cyan_img.show()
blend.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`ImageOps.colorize`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-imageops-colorize-method/) expects a **grayscale** image as input and applies a color scale to it. That is what [mode "L"](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes) stands for (L = **L**uminosity = grayscale).

If the image you are loading is stored in RGB(A) format then you can convert it to grayscale like this:

```
img = Image.open("image.jpg").convert("L")
```